# How can i modify the styles of this text when used with a function in angular js?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

```
 addSystemTextToDialog("please select one of the offerings and Hit enter");
```

I have the above function to display the text mentioned,how can i add the styles to this function,
I want to turn the text color to red when displayed using angular js

Comment: Please paste your efforts what you have tried earlier and on what point you were stuck

Comment: `showCode("You need to show the code of addSystemTextToDialog function")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are printing this in html document, you can do this

```
 addSystemTextToDialog("<p class='my'>please select one of the offerings and Hit enter</p>");
```

then in your style, assign css as you want

```
<style>
p.my
{
....
.....
}
</style>
```